# Java Heap Size Issue While uploading Images in Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, image-processing, applet

My task is Compressing an Image , re-sizing it and finally Watermark is added to that Image. Where I am facing issue is While writing Watermark to that Image   Eclipse throws an error that "Java Heap Size Error" in

```
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
                   icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(),
                   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

With, the help of Stackoverflow.com I have fixed this issue by Increasing the Java Virtual Memory by adding -Xmx1024m in Eclipse VM. But while I am running this Applet in Browser then my task in uncompleted ie, Image processing strucks at watermark writing area. I have changed the Java Virtual Memory size in Java Control panel as -Xmx1024m and still i am facing the same Issue.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

My Code Effort and where I am Facing issue is given below.

```
public BufferedImage setWaterMark(File imageFile, String watermark, String fontName, int fontSize, float opaque,int offsetSize,int intAngle,int intChkbox) throws Exception {


    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageFile.getPath());
     System.out.println("Reading Image at Water mark");


     BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
                   icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(),
                   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
   g2d.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

   g2d.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
   g2d.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
   AlphaComposite alpha = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
           AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opaque);
   g2d.setComposite(alpha);
   g2d.setColor(Color.white);
   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Applet Deployment Parameters](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html):

```html
<APPLET archive="my_applet.jar" code="MyApplet" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m">
</APPLET>
```

It can also be done in the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) file if the applet is launched by [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it now. I am facing this issue when am processing with Long Width and Height images (min 10000X5000). Anyways I will come back to you after trying this fix.

Comment: <applet 
  codebase = "." 
  code     = "ImageProcessor.class" 
  archive  = "VTCompression.jar" 
  name     = "VT Image Compression " 
  width    = "510" 
  height   = "630" 
  hspace   = "0" 
  vspace   = "0" 
  align    = "top" 
  
    > 
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xms1024m -Xmx1624m">
    </applet>                                                                                       the above is my Applet code that already I worked with @Andrew Thomson

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: Sorted out in my local machine. still looking solid solution to fix it in Client's side machine and Browser.

Comment: Huh.. what?  That applet element you quoted should work in a browser for the clients as well, unless they are running an ancient version of Java (I think that parameter was introduced around Java 1.5)!

Answer (score -1):

```
1. open your .java file that contains the main().
2. Right click -> Select "Run As"-> "Run Configuration".
3. In the resulting Screen, under "Java Application" see if there exist ur already executed entry.If not Right click on "Java
Application" to create one.
4. Select that entry
5. Select "Arguments" tab.
6. Under "VM Argumets" area, type `-Xmx1g`
7. click Apply followed by Run button.
```

Try the above steps and see whether you are getting the same error or not.

Comment: While I am running this in Eclipse, its not a prob and I have done this process already and succeeded. The Real one is when I am running this Applet in Clients' Browser , I get struck. :-(

Comment: As an aside: While this might work for the person making the applet, it will not work for the end user.  You'd lose them at point 1.

Comment: If you are running ur applet using `appletviewer` , Then give `-J-mx1g` as argument. That is, the command will look like -> `appletviewer -J-mx64m <urpage.html>`

Comment: @Sujai - Am doing this for Client purpose only. Made my Applet signed and its actually running good so for. The only prob is when Image Width and Height crosses 10000+ the  java Heap size issue stops the process exactly at reading icon.getIconWidth() and icon.getIconHeight() . While in local I could fix it by changing the Eclipse Run-time VM and as well as I tried to fix this issue in client's browser by changing their Java Control panel VM. But in Some case its working and for some case its not working. For Java(32-bit) its working but for Java its not working.

Comment: Just to confirm. The client might be using the browser to open the html file.right. If yes, then try the above mentioned command in appletviewer and open the html via appletviewer.

Comment: @SurajMathew  ..the more you comment, the less I'm understanding where you are coming from.  We aren't talking about instructions for the **applet developer.**  The aim is to get it working for the **end user.**  As far as the end user goes, anything beyond *'Click OK when prompted'* is ..far too much. -1 for completely missing the point, then laboring the issue.  This answer is noise.

Comment: @Andrew.... I never insisted the reporter to do that.. That was just a suggestion. through this site.. anyone can post his suggesstion for a problem. It doesn't mean that it will always be a positive one.I have requested to delete my Stackoverflow account. Hope you are happy...